# How can i add textfield in text widget? - Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

I want to add textfield in a text widget.

like that:

I want to ___ textfield in a text widget.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two seperate Text widgets and a TextField widget in between, all in a Row widget. like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: Center(
          child: MyStatefulWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool isTextFieldEnabled = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Row(
      children: [
        Text('I want to'),
        Container(
          width: 200,
          child: TextField(
            enabled: isTextFieldEnabled,
          ),
        ),
        Text('textfield in a text widget.'),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But i want to change word with textfield in this text widget.

Comment: what do you mean? how do you want to change the word? do you want to turn the value typed in text field to a text after submitting?

Comment: No.
String value = "";
String sentence = "I want to add textfield in a text widget.";
Split this sentence 
if value == "add" ? delete value and create a simple textfield : value

Comment: I cannot really understand what you want to achieve here. can you add more code in the question and explain it more clearly?